# How to transform XML file into a class/object structure in Python?

Tags: python, xml, parsing, database-design, object-oriented-database

I want to use an XML file containing a collection of objects (it is a GML file for GIS applications) as input in models i am developping. Herefore, i want to transform the objects in my XML file into real Python objects so i can use them easily. Is there an easy way of doing this, i.e. transforming the XML collection into a database of objects ?

Comment: Could you provide some input/output example? It should be possible to parse the xml and create the structure you're looking for.

Comment: Well, i have the GML file and its XSD, e.g. like  http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/2.1.2/feature.xsd and i am looking for an automated way in Python to make from this XSD a class type and from the GML (which is a collection of features) a list of objects. (But even parsing the GML seems to result in some problems ...)

Comment: Have you looked at [`lxml.objectify`](http://lxml.de/objectify.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try generateDS.  [generateDS homepage](http://www.rexx.com/~dkuhlman/generateDS.html).  Last time I used it was a couple of years ago, and it had some limitations then---there were some valid xsd features that it would not handle.  Looks like it has been evolving since then; those limitations may have disappeared, or they may not apply to your situation anyway.

Comment: This indeed looks like what i am looking for, but i'm struggeling to make it work

Comment: It works ! Thank you, dis indeed is absolutly what i needed, automatically generating python code classes from my XML documents.

Comment: It was very helpful for me a couple of years ago.  Big thanks to Dave Kuhlman.